# What does the phrase "never the mane shall tweet" mean?

Tags: meaning, jokes, humor

> It has long been known that birds will occasionally build nests in the
>   manes of horses.  The only known solution to this problem is to
>   sprinkle baker's yeast in the mane, for, as we all know, yeast is
>   yeast and nest is nest, and never the mane shall tweet.

What is the meaning of the above quote? I am confused by the phrases *manes of horses* and *never the mane shall tweet*. An online dictionary says that *manes* is the plural form, but its singular form, *mane*, has an entirely different meaning.

Comment: I'm curious about the difference between _mane_ and _manes_!  Here it has its ordinary meaning: the long hair on a horse's neck (or a lion's head).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is joke. It is an example of a [spoonerism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism) in which the beginnings of words have been changed or swapped.  The normal English saying:

> East is East and West is West and never the twain shall meet.

has been humorously rearranged to be the punchline of a joke.

Comment: Including the phrase w/o the spoonerism involved, in the answer would improve its quality, IMO.

Comment: There used to be a large number of stories published in monthly magazines that were actually just elaborate setups for groan-inducing punchlines like "Sloan's teddy wins the race" or "What was that laser I sawed you with last night? ... That was no laser, that was my knife" and so on.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher- I don't understand.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz- What's the difference between a group of very clever pygmies and the girls track team?   The pygmies are a bunch of cunning runts.

Comment: @Jim: What's the difference between a rooster and a shyster? A rooster clucks defiance.

Comment: It's worth mention that the original is a line of a poem by Kipling.